# Regex javascript website with / at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

So, this is my Regex code:

```
state = /\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i.test($(this).val())
```

Now if someone just type a

" http://www. "

It will recognize him like a good URL Address. but, i want something like this

URL must be like this " http://www.example.com/ "

With the **/** at the end (**important**), with **http://** and **www.** at the start, and every domain (.com, .net etc.)

If someone type url like this

" http://www.example.com "

To give him an error

Comment: What about `http://www.example.com/file.htm`? That is, do you want a `/` at the end of the URL, or just after the domain?

Comment: Nope, must be only URL of site without files,
Just after the domain

Comment: `if (url.slice(-1) !== "/") fail`

Comment: I would exact the parts of the URL using a simpler regex then later check if the scheme is "http" or whatever you want to allow. Same with the host name.

Comment: Why are you not allowing URLs without the trailing slash? It is still a valid URL.

Answer (score 2):

To test for an ending `/`, Simply add `\/$` at the end of your RegExp.

If you want to make sure there's nothing after the `/` after the domain name, remove `\/` from the previous `[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]` statement. This way you only allow one `/` in your URL.

Also I'm pretty sure you dont' want the following characters in your URL `|%@#&?=!:,;+`

```
/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9_.]*[a-z]\/$/i
```

Test JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdk6fjxc/1/